# how to convert array of bytes to int64 in perl

Tags: perl

I have an specific problem to solve in Perl 5 (using minimal external dependencies, if possible compatible with version 5.12), related to decode an array of bytes like this:

```perl
my @data = (0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x84, 0x14, 0x40, 0x32);
```

and I want to extract a number like this: 15100821554

I try several variations of pack / unpack without success like

```perl
say(unpack("Q", pack("C*", @data)));
```

print 3620916657624449024

The equivalent code in go is something like this

```golang
data := []byte{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x84, 0x14, 0x40, 0x32}
deciseconds := int64(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(data))
```

can be executed here: https://play.golang.org/p/I2J45H-sn-H

any ideas?

Comment: `Q` assumes native endianness, while `Q<` and `Q>` unpack little- and big-endian numbers respectively. See [Formats for Packing and Unpacking Numbers](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11111036)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there, the following works:

```
say unpack 'Q', pack 'C*', reverse @data;
#                          ~~~~~~~
```

It means you need the opposite endianness, which translates to pack in the following way:

```
unpack 'Q>', pack 'C*', @data;
#        ^
```

Comment: The `Q>` solution is more straightforward, more extensible (e.g. you could use it as part of a larger pattern such as `Q>*`), and it works on more machines (the `reverse` solution, ironically, doesn't work on big-endian machines).

Answer (score -1):

Desired result can be achieved with following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $num = 0;
my @data = (0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x84, 0x14, 0x40, 0x32);

$num = ($num<<8) + $_ for @data;

say $num;
```

Output

```
15100821554
```

NOTE: unpack is a correct way to make conversion